Changing Video's Sound with another sound with using Shotcut
I want to replace the sound of the video file I have with another video file. I use a program called Shotcut. I have a 250 mb video, mkv file, audio in opus. I change the sound with Shotcut and select h.264 from the loseless section, the resulting file is 5.6 GB. Please help me. Codec Selection Video Time Line Export Settings I know i set Quality to 100 but i just want to make output same with input file
I was expecting the resulting file to only make a difference of 200 MB or so.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

are you asking for a Shotcut usage tutorial?

Part of the issue is that simply transcoding MKV to MP4 h.264 produces far larger files. Try transcoding the MKV to an editable format first, and see how large it becomes.
